# How do you output a $row->field_data in a custom views PHP field?

Tags: 7, views

I have the following Custom PHP Views field: http://prntscr.com/1dd8m0

I did a print_r($row), but I keep getting output that doesnt match what I have in those fields: http://prntscr.com/1dd9ls

Does anyone know why?

My end result is to be able to do a preg_replace() on the fields loaded before it. End result would be:

> print preg_replace('foo','bar', $row->path);

Comment: Try using `dpm` instead of `print_r`. Install the [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module and in your PHP write `dpm($row);`. That should provide a better representation of the `$row` object than `print_r` is currently providing.